# Is there a way to know why I can't install SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've installed SQL Server before and I can't connect to it, so I uninstall it. But when I try to install again it show an error messages. can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: Is there maybe more info in that log folder about what went wrong? Did you reboot your system after uninstalling (never hurts to do that)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message as text; not only does this make it readable on small screens and by little with poor eyesight, it ensures that anytime facing the same issue in future will be able to find this question and hopefully the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have **not uninstalled all components** of sql server. Please uninstall all sql related components from control panel. Then you can install `sql server` properly.
Please refer this for detail information
[Invalid command line argument error](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/07/30/sql-server-2019-installation-failure-invalid-command-line-argument-consult-the-windows-installer-sdk-for-detailed-command-line-help/)

Comment: How I can remove all related components, because in my control panel all sql server related has been uninstalled

Comment: may be this can help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/uninstall-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=Windows10